# How to define a GraphQLType for a list of strings and numbers?

Tags: javascript, graphql, graphql-js

I have an object on the server that looks like this:

`{ data: [[1,"asds"], [4, "ssd", [94, "Ads"]] }`

How do I define a type in GraphQL (using graphql.js) to describe this? Basically something like GraphQLList(GraphQLString | GraphQLInt).

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use GraphQLScalarType to accept any value:

```
var AnyValueScalar = new graphql.GraphQLScalarType({
  name: 'AnyValueScalar',
  serialize: anyValue,
  parseValue: anyValue,
  parseLiteral(ast) {
      return anyValue(ast.value);
  }
});

function anyValue(value) {
  return value
}
```

Define the Query type field data

```
var queryType = new graphql.GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: {
    data: {
      type: AnyValueScalar,
      resolve: function(_,args){
        return [[1,"asds"], [4, "ssd", [94, "Ads"]]]
      }
    }
  }
});
```

If you query in QraphiQL as below

```
query {
  data
}
```

It should have result

```
{
  "data": {
    "data": [
      [
        1,
        "asds"
      ],
      [
        4,
        "ssd",
        [
          94,
          "Ads"
        ]
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```